# Will replacing php coding, in the index.php file with `get_template_part` tags, reduce website performance?

Tags: php, wordpress

My index.php file currently includes content such as:

- Latest Products
- Product Testimonials
- Subscribe to us
- Blogs

Rather than have the entire coding for this, placed into my index.php file, I would like to create a template file for each 'section' and then call it in the index.php file, using the `get_template_part` tag.

So much so, my index.php would then become a file housing a series of `get_template_part` entries.

Is anyone aware of any issues that this may cause, such as website load speed or any compatibility issues?

Comment: The difference would be milliseconds, if any.

Comment: Craig, what you're talking about doing is a completely reasonable and widely-used practice both in WordPress and the development community at large. If code for a specific section is getting long-winded, feel free to break it out into its own file for ease of management. Load speed difference will be negligible.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since originally posting this question, I have experimented with the layout of the `index.php` file, where I used Google's PageSpeed Insights and Pingdom to measure any performance changes.

Firstly, I placed the following content into the `index.php` file:

- Latest Products
- Product Testimonials
- Subscribe to us
- Blogs

I then took out the above content and then placed the content into assigned Templates files.  I then entered the appropriate `get_template_part` tags into the 'index.php' files, as to call each Template file.

Whilst there was a slight reduction in page load speed, it was negligible.  On one occasion, the change in PageSpeed was a reduction of speed of 0.0003s.

Of course, it is up to the site creator on how they want to go about the creation for their website but I feel this is a good trade off, considering it would result in a more organised website.